# Interactive visualization does not work in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, visualization

I am a beginner for interactive visualization in Jupyter Notebook. Below is the Python code I have been using.

```
import altair as alt
alt.Chart(data=dt).mark_point().encode(
    x="seq",
    y="v3",
    color="v2",
    size='v1'
)
```

`dt` is the data I have created, and below is the data structure:

```
        seq      v1     v2    v3    color
0       1100      3     35    11    red
1       1101      5     41    12    red
2       1102      1     19     9    yellow
3       1103      1     19    11    blue
4       1104      5     44    14    red
```

After running the code, nothing is showing.

Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: What are you basing your code on? I'm not following. You seem to import altair and then plotly. But then you just use altair? So why is Plotly being invoked? Have you installed the packages and tried the "getting started" examples and they worked?

Comment: I've never used Altair but for Plotly there's a guide to use it in Jupyter notebooks as part of their officiel docs: https://plotly.com/python/ipython-notebook-tutorial/ . I'm sure there's something similar for Altair as well.

Comment: strange, i ran your code, and it renders the chart

Comment: @NataliaGoloskokova, Which environment did you use? Mine is Python 3 (ipykernel). Thank you.

Comment: @Wayne, altair is the package i am using.

Comment: @Sophia - same Python 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To follow up on Natalia's comment. Your code does work and I can show you a place where it works.

Go [to the starting page of the Altair tutorial here](https://altair-viz.github.io/altair-tutorial/README.html) and at the bottom, click on the `'launch binder'` badge. A session will spin up.

When it opens, make a new notebook by pressing the tile under 'Notebook' in the Launcher pane.
Then paste in the following code:

```py
s='''        seq      v1     v2    v3    color
0       1100      3     35    11    red
1       1101      5     41    12    red
2       1102      1     19     9    yellow
3       1103      1     19    11    blue
4       1104      5     44    14    red
'''
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
dt = pd.read_table(StringIO(s),header=0, index_col=0, delim_whitespace= True)
import altair as alt
#import plotly.express as px
alt.Chart(data=dt).mark_point().encode(
    x="seq",
    y="v3",
    color="v2",
    size='v1'
)
```

(I commented out the plotly line because you don't explain why it was there, and plotly isn't installed in the environment that the tutorial provides.)

That will display a plot.

If you prefer to work in the classic notebook interface, under '`Help`' along the File menu at the top, select '`Launch Classic Notebook`'.

---

If you don't see the same thing as there where you are working, then possibly you haven't installed things correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I can’t add the printscreen to the comment, so here it is
[image: pip install altair==5.0.0rc1]