# Parsing Table using read.html output error

Tags: python, jupyter

I am following a youtube instruction video in scrapping epl matches but using

```
import pandas as pd
matches = pd.read_html(data.text, match="Scores & Fixtures")[0]
```

comes up as an error

```
FutureWarning: Passing literal html to 'read_html' is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To read from a literal string, wrap it in a 'StringIO' object.
  matches = pd.read_html(data.text, match="Scores & Fixtures")[0]
```

I tried wrapping but wasn't able to so so

Comment: I think you should repalce data.text with StringIO object
Something like this 

from io import StringIO

file = StringIO(  data.text)
pd.read_htrml(file, match ......)

Comment: What exactly did you do  to wrap and what was the error?

Comment: It looks like a warning and not an error. And like the other two have pointed out, your post does not reflect wrapping it as a StringIO object. I have an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76008169/8508004) of an example where I wrap it properly to read in a text string using `pandas.read_csv()`. You would do it similar but replace it with `pandas.read_html()` if indeed is HTML. We'd be able to help more with an actual example and complete code as instructed to do in [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Plus it would help if you use fenced code ...

Comment: <cotninued> blocks to share code properly formatted like I do in the answer I pointed you at. See where it says "Use fenced code blocks by surrounding your code" [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/8508004).

Answer (score 0):

```py
# Deprecated approach (avoid this)
html_string = "<html><body><p>Hello, World!</p></body></html>"
process_html(html_string)

# Recommended approach
import io

# For string input
html_string_io = io.StringIO("<html><body><p>Hello, World!</p></body></html>")
process_html(html_string_io.read())

# For byte input
html_bytes_io = io.BytesIO(b"<html><body><p>Hello, World!</p></body></html>")
process_html(html_bytes_io.read())
```